# Java out of process component for multithreading

Tags: java, multithreading, jvm

I recently started to work in a java project and i am from vb background.

Is there any equivalent of VB6 ActiveX Exe development in java which enables a component to run in its own process and useful in multi threading requirements?

Comment: Java supports multithreading well, but all its multithreading is in-process.

Comment: Unless there are really persuasive arguments to run different parts of UI in different processes, I really suggest to use multi-threading inside one process since in 99% of cases this will be more performant and efficient.

Answer (score 0):

I think the only way is to start another JVM from the JVM you're currently in.
But I don't really see why someone would want to do that in a real-world scenario.
Apart from that all multi-threaded execution happens in the same JVM you're in.

Answer (score 0):

Java has API for working with external processes.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html

You can use ProcessBuilder to create it.